# How many local databases can simultaneously syncronize to the server database using merge (pull) replication?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

The organization that I am working for is in the process of moving our SQL Server databases onto a virtual server. One of the applications has a master copy of that apps database on the server with 35 local copies of the database on laptops that are used in the field.

The local databases sync to the main database using Microsoft Replication Merge (Pull) Services. A key step in this migration process will be to have all of the users sync their laptops to the main database prior to moving the server copy onto the virtual server.

Once the main database is moved and the local copies are repointed, we will need to sync again to verify that each laptop is communicating properly with the new database location. This is a SQL Server 2008 R2 database. Each local copy uses SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

Does anyone have experience with attempting to sync multiple local copies of a database simultaneously? Is anyone aware of the limits?

The database is quite large. There are over 30 tables being replicated with each table containing several hundred thousand records. Overall database size on each local copy when installed is currently 8.4 GB (yes, we are aware that we are getting close to the 10 GB limit with Express, we are addressing that issue separately)

Thanks,

Bill

Answer (score 0):

[SymmetricDS](http://www.jumpmind.com/products/symmetricds/overview) can replicate MS SQL and works with express edition.  The amount of the data your replicating would not be an issue.  You can configure the frequency of the replication and you have the ability to initiate a full load of all tables or a partial load of selected tables at any point.  This might be what you want after pointing the clients to a new location.